# How to play hyperlink to mp3 on Android

Tags: audio, music-player

When I lick on a link to a mp3 file on in web page on my Android phone. It starts playing it on Google music player, but as soon as I hit home button or back button it stops playing. I know why it is behaving such a way (Activity that is playing the audio file is destroyed when back button is hit or paused when home button is pressed). Problem is I'm not able to figure out a way to work around this limitation.

One thing that I can do is copy and paste a link in a player that accepts hyperlink as input. Unfortunately Google music player does not.

Has any onw figured out a work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

I use [MixZing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixzing.basic&hl=en) music player. I have set it as default player for music and when I click a mp3 file link in browser, it opens the file in MixZing by default and streaming works well. It plays the mp3 file in background when you press the back button.

This is an alternate solution. I don't thing it is possible to play the mp3 links in background in Android's default music player.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. I usually long-press on the link and choose `Save Link` to save the mp3 file to my phone, then I just play it in my media app of choice.

Comment: That trick works if you are on android stock Browser. Chrome for android does not have save link as option. Also I'm using google reader which also does not have this option.

Comment: Chrome for Android should have this option available [as of v0.18.4409.2396](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116823) (this was just resolved a few hours ago as of this post). As for Google Reader for Android you might be out of luck for a `Save Link` option.